# Read/write message using RFHUTILC into ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

Can we write and read the message using RFHUTILC into ActiveMQ?

I know RFHUTILC is used for writing and reading messages into IBM MQ but my requirement is to pull/Read a message from Apache ActiveMQ.

Comment: What protocol does RFHUTILC speak?  Unless it uses an industry standard protocol like AMQP, STOMP, MQTT, etc. I don't see how it would be able to talk to ActiveMQ.

Answer (score 0):

RFHUTILC won't work, as it only talks IBM MQ's protocol, which is non-standard and specific to IBM MQ. ActiveMQ supports a number of standard and open source protocols, as @Justin Bertram mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

RFHUTIL is IBM MQ only. I made a smilar tool called [A](https://github.com/fmtn/a) that has been around sometime for ActiveMQ (generic JMS with OpenWire/ActiveMQ, HornetQ and AMQP protocols bundled) that you can use instead. It's command line though, no GUI. Free/open source.

https://github.com/fmtn/a

There are of course other similar utilities with GUI, such as [Hawt.IO](http://hawt.io/) among others. Some are a bit outdated though (Hermes JMS).